# python think 2 is not a prime number

Tags: python, math, primes

I wrote a python script tho for prim numbers that check number and give result.the problem is python think 2 is not a prime number what should i do?
is there any way to solve this? thx

```
    def prime(n):
    aval = True
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n% i == 0:
            aval = False
        else:
            return aval

for j in range(1,3):
    print(j,prime(j))
```

and this is the result:
1 None
2 None

Comment: You only hit the return statement if you find a number that is not a factor. Otherwise you run off the end of the function and return None.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but is not "python thinks", is your function who isn't working properly. Python doesn't think

Comment: I there another factor besides 2 and 1 for 2 that we aren't aware of?

Comment: Here is a huge hint of the issue: on 1 and 2, your function returns `None`, not `True` or `False`. There are two ways a function can return `None` in python: either by an explicit `return None`, or by the absence of a `return`. In your case, there is only a `return` in the `else` branch; it is not always reached; and sometimes it is reached for the wrong reasons. See tadman's answer for how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your logic is a little mangled, but it's easy to untangle:

```
def prime(n):
  for i in range(2,n):
    if n % i == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Where this now breaks out of the loop if it detects a miss.

Comment: it doesnt make any change and it think that 9 is a prime too omg

Comment: This returns `True` for me on `prime(2)` and `False` for `prime(4)` for example.

Comment: @amirdadfar9192 this solution should work. Are you sure it returns `True` for 9? On my computer it correctly returns `False` for 9.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way to do it would be this.

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n)-1)))
```